# Replace content between two tags with preg_replace (php)

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a string like this:

`(link)there is link1(/link), (link)there is link2(/link)`

Now i want to set the links that it look like this:

`<a href='there is link1'>there is link1</a>, <a href='there is link2'>there is link2</a>`

I tried with preg_replace but the result is an error (`Unknown modifier 'l'`)

`preg_replace("/\(link\).*?\(/link\)/U", "<a href='$1'>$1</a>", $return);`

Comment: you need to escape the slash(es)

Comment: but i escaped the slashes with an "\" or?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You actually are not far from the correct result:

1. Escape the `/` before `link` (else, it will be treated as a regex delimiter and ruin your regex completely)
2. Use single quotes to declare the regex (or you'll have to use double backslashes for escaping regex metacharacters)
3. Add a capture group around `.*?` (so that you could later refer to with `$1`)
4. Do not use `U` as it will make `.*?` greedy

Here is [my suggestion](https://regex101.com/r/bP1kZ8/1):

```
\(link\)(.*?)\(\/link\)
```

And [PHP code](http://ideone.com/2sybOT):

```
$re = '/\(link\)(.*?)\(\/link\)/'; 
$str = "(link)there is link1(/link), (link)there is link2(/link)"; 
$subst = "<a href='$1'>$1</a>"; 
$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
echo $result;
```

To also `urlencode()` the `href` parameter, you can use the `preg_replace_callback` function and manipulate the `$m[1]` (capture group value) inside it:

```
$result = preg_replace_callback($re, function ($m) {
    return "<a href=" . urlencode($m[1]) . "'>" . $m[1] . "</a>";
  }, $str);
```

See [another IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/F5FDgr)

Comment: Is it possible to urlencode() the $1 in the `href` parameter?